# Golang - Hijack Arguments

Tags: http, go, go-http

When using [Hijack()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Hijacker) with a `http.ResponseWriter` instance

> Hijack() (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error)

What is the difference between reading from the `net.Conn` and the `*bufio.ReadWriter`?

Comment: The `*bufio.ReadWriter` is buffer IO for the underlying `net.Conn`. Are you asking *why* you would use buffered Reads?

Comment: Ahh I see. No I was just confused why there is two ways of getting the same data... :) thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`net.Conn.Read` and `*bufio.ReadWriter.Read` both read from the same connection, but the latter is buffered. The `Hijack` method in the standard "net/http" package directly returns the `net.Conn` wrapped in a `bufio.ReadWriter`, using the same `*bufio.Reader` that was already allocated for the http request.

It's possible that there is still data buffered in the `bufio.Reader` which you may miss when reading directly from the network connection. If you want to use the `net.Conn` directly, you should check if there is buffered data already with [`Reader.Buffered`](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.Buffered), and handle that according to the protocol being used.

In general, you should prefer to use `bufio.ReadWriter`, as it will be more efficient for non-optimally sized reads and writes to the network.

The  `net.Conn` is still needed to handle the Read and Write deadlines, to close the `net.Conn` when you're done, and for any other network-specific activities.

Comment: If the protocol is such that the client must wait for a response from the server before writing data after the HTTP request header, then the server application can ignore the bufio wrapper after [checking for a client error](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.Buffered). The websocket protocol is an example of where this can be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I'm new to go and people like you encourage me to not give up! I really appreciate it! Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Their difference is buffered IO.

net.Conn implements Read() and Write() thus implementing io.Reader and io.Writer. This is why bufio can wrap it up as a *buffered* ReadWriter and further implement functions on top using those two methods in a buffered manner.

If you only want to use Read() and Write(), you can just stick with net.Conn, otherwise you can take advantage for the buffered ReadWriter methods.

See https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader and https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer

Comment: There is a difference between buffered and unbuffered IO.

Comment: Ok, but you only corrected the first statement. Even if you're "only going to use Read() and Write()", you still will often want buffered IO.

Comment: Buffered IO is optional so I clarified that just now.